# Area of a Triangle - what is the formula?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Triangle $ABC$: $A(1; 4), ~B(7; 8), ~C(9; 2)$.

I need to find the area of a triangle. I found this solution:

[image: Area of a Triangle]

But, what is the formula?

Comment: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/2683e22449e715a9edcbee4174b4ea4a3f7dfb44 ?

Comment: It is called the "[Shoelace formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vertices are $(0,0), (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$, the area is given by $\frac{1}{2}|x_1y_2 - x_2y_1|$. Now, transferring the origin to $A$, the coordinates of the vertices become $(x_B-x_A, y_B-y_A), (x_C-x_A, y_C-y_A), (0,0)$ and hence the area is 
$$\frac{1}{2}|(x_B-x_A)(y_C-y_A) - (x_C-x_A)(y_B-y_A)|$$

Comment: What is the formula?

Comment: Area $=\frac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 1 & x_2 & y_2 \\ 1 & x_3 & y_3\end{vmatrix}$ for the triangle with $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ as vertices.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is a simplified form of this:
‎\begin{eqnarray*}‎
  ‎S=\frac12‎
  ‎\Big[‎
‎ \left|\begin{array}{rr}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2\end{array}\right|‎
 +
‎ \left|\begin{array}{rr}x_2&x_3\\y_2&y_3\end{array}\right|‎
‎ %+\left|\begin{array}{rr}x_3&x_4\\y_3&y_4\end{array}\right|‎
 +
‎ \cdots‎
 +
‎ \left|\begin{array}{rr}x_{n-1}&x_n\\y_{n-1}&y_n\end{array}\right|‎
 +
‎ \left|\begin{array}{rr}x_n&x_1\\y_n&y_1\end{array}\right|‎
  ‎\Big]‎
‎\end{eqnarray*}‎
Where $n$ points 
‎$$
P_1\Big|\begin{array}{r}x_1\\y_1\end{array},~~P_2\Big|\begin{array}{r}x_2\\y_2\end{array},~~P_3\Big|\begin{array}{r}x_3\\y_3\end{array},~~\cdots~~,~~P_n\Big|\begin{array}{r}x_n\\y_n\end{array}
$$‎
are vertices of a plane polygon. For your points $A(1,4), ~B(7,8), ~C(9,2)$:
‎\begin{eqnarray*}‎
  ‎S=\frac12‎
  ‎\Big[‎
‎ \left|\begin{array}{rr}1&7\\4&8\end{array}\right|‎
 +
‎ \left|\begin{array}{rr}7&9\\8&2\end{array}\right|‎
‎ +\left|\begin{array}{rr}9&1\\2&4\end{array}\right|‎
  ‎\Big]‎=\frac12|8-28+14-72+36-2|=22
‎\end{eqnarray*}‎

Answer (score 1):

This is use of determinant to find area.

$$\frac 12
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
x_A & x_B & x_C \\
y_A & y_B & y_C 
\end{array} \right|
$$

Operate **Column 2 - Column 1** and **Column 3 - Column 1**. You get,

$$\frac 12
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
x_A & x_B - x_A & x_C - x_A \\
y_A & y_B - y_A & y_C - y_A
\end{array} \right|
$$

Solve it you got above formula.